# SVG hyperlink issue with angular 6

Tags: html, svg, angular6

I display an **SVG** file using **HTML** `img` tag through the `.html` file of an Angular 6 component. Let's call this **SVG** file `a.svg`.

This `a.svg` image contains parts that are linked to other **SVG** files, and let's just consider the first of them, named `b.svg`.

All the **SVG** files are static. They are place in a subfolder of `assets` in Angular 6 application folder.

When I open `a.svg` directly under my Internet browser, I can click on hyperlinked parts and navigate to `b.svg`, without any problem.

Under Angular 6, file `a.svg` is displayed correctly, but apparently, I can not click on interactive parts.

I investigate the issue without being able to find a real clue about the root cause of such behabior. Maybe, related to security issue.  I wonder

1. is this a desired behavior of Angular 6?
2. is there a way to tell Angular 6, to allow user interaction on these images ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the right way to do so.

First, read [security guide for angular](https://angular.io/guide/security) which provides many good hints, although far from being exhaustive.

To make my code run smoothly, this is what I changed

**Firstly**, in angular component `.html` file, I changed the **HTML** `img` tag into a `div` tag, on which I used the `[innerHTML]` binding to an internal property named svgFromFile

```
<div class='e2e-inner-html-bound' [innerHTML]='svgFromFile'></div>
```

**Then**, in angular component `.ts` file, I changed the implementation to use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` on the content of the target **SVG** file

```
this.fn = '/assets/urba/diagram/' + params['fn'] + '.svg'; // from route parameter to image asset to be served

this.http.get(this.fn, {
  responseType: 'text'
}).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.svgFromFile = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
  },
  error => console.log('svgFromFile', error)
);
```

Doing so, embedded URLS in **SVG** file are now active and dereferenceable.